# Workflow for Servicenow Incidents

Tags: workflow, servicenow

I was just checking for the feasibility for workflows on Incidents and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387079/servicenow-how-to-create-a-workflow-that-runs-on-incident-update/32653038#32653038).

It seems it is possible to have workflows on incidents.

I just need to know is there any proper way to do it..I am kind of new bee to Servicenow. anyone share the experience and how can I achieve this. 
For instance, a simple approval workflow on the Incident..

Thanks in advance
 Chitra

Answer (score 6):

A few basic changes can get this going, since the Incident table has the Approval fields and such associated to it.

**Alter the Incident form**

- Go to an **Incident**
- Configure (Fuji) or Personalize (Eureka) the following

  - **Form Layout** > Add the **Approval** field
  - **Related Lists** > Add the **Approvers** list

**Create workflow for approval**

Next you want a workflow to run when an Incident is created.

- Go to the *Workflow Editor*
- Create a new workflow with the following

  - **Name**: Incident - Approval
  - **Table**: Incident [incident]
  - **Activity pinning**: Set by activity
  - **If condition matches**: Run the workflow
  - **Condition**: Leave blank

Leaving the *Condition* blank will cause it to run on creation of an *Incident*.

**Fill out workflow**

Add the following activities

- Approval Action

  - **Name**: Set Requested
  - **Action**: Mark task as requested
- Approval Group

  - **Name**: Wait for Approval
  - **Groups**: Select the group who will approve all Incidents, such as the Help Desk. Important: This group must have group members or this will automatically be approved.
  - Leave the rest as default
- Approval Action

  - **Name**: Incident Approved
  - **Action**: Mark task approved
  - After creating this, connect the *Approved* node from the **Wait for Approval** action you just made to this activity. Also connect the *Always* node to the **End Activity**
- Approval Action

  - **Name**: Incident Rejected
  - **Action**: Mark task rejected
  - Like above, connect the *Rejected* node from the **Wait for Approval** action you just made to this activity and connect the Always node to the **End Activity**

**Test the workflow**

Finally you can test this by Publishing this workflow and creating an Incident.

- Publish your workflow
- Create a new *Incident* and open it
- Note the **Approval** field should say *Approval requested*
- Under the **Approvals** Related List, you should see a list of all users inside of the group you set within the **Wait for Approval** Activity
- If any user in this list *Approves* it, the **Approval** field will change to Approved
- If any user in this list *Rejects* it, the **Approval** field will change to Rejected

I've put in a sample picture below, but this is a very basic workflow. It can get more complex as your needs change or are different. Hopefully this gets you on your way to a start.

[image]