# Workflow - ServiceNow

Tags: workflow, servicenow

I'm new to ServiceNow and followed this tutorial [Workflow for Servicenow Incidents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690352/workflow-for-servicenow-incidents) to create a simple workflow for an approval request.

The steps that I took on studio of my developer instance:

- Created an application "ServiceNowApp"
- Created a table "Order"
- Created a field "Status"
- Created a workflow as described on tutorial

My intention is to trigger the workflow by the creation of a new record on Order table and change the Status field based on the decision of the responsable user.

Any advice is welcome to accomplish the goal

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the `Order` table, make sure it extends the `Task` table. This will allow you to add an *approval* to it.

Based on that post you should be able to follow things as you build it out in the same manner, just select your `Order` table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using core activities `Approval - User` and `Set Values` in your workflow.
(Your `Order` table doesn't need to extend `Task` table.)

`Approval - User` creates an approval record for the responsible user and the user can open the record to approve/reject it in the `My Approvals` menu.

`Set Values` sets `Status` field to any value.

Your workflow would look like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the trigger conditions on the workflow itself while creating the workflow.
You can also choose the table and then choose any status field you want to act on the requests.
Below is the snapshot which might help you understand the concept.
[image]
Let me know if you need any help.

Regards,
Ishaan